# Can't import Rails plugin from GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, plugins, github

I want to use the Typus plugin in my rails application, but i can't install it.

```
$ script/plugin install git://github.com/fesplugas/typus.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /...../vendor/plugins/typus/.git/

$ script/generate typus
Couldn't find 'typus' generator

$ ls -al vendor/plugins/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 ***  staff   68 Aug 23 16:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 ***  staff  102 Aug 23 16:37 ..

$ rails -v
Rails 2.3.8
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was an open rails ticket for a very similar issue that was fixed by making some changes to the ~/.gitconfig file.  Take a look at this comment.  Hopefully it at least gets you going on the right direction:

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3743-scriptplugin-install-gitwhatever-does-nothing#ticket-3743-9

Comment: Great, thanks!
Deleting the lines from my ~/.gitconfig mentioned in the comments fixes the problem.